# CORS request not valid - missing headers?

Tags: http-headers, cors

I am trying to upload an image to a finagle (netty) server. For the OPTIONS request I return the following:

```
curl -X OPTIONS http://localhost:8686/images -i                                                         
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
```

Browser (FireBug): http://s15.postimg.org/vtdzyfshn/Screen_Shot_2014_09_02_at_9_49_05_PM.png

The following POST request fails with

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote 
resource at http://localhost:8686/images. This can be fixed by moving the resource 
to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

FireBug 1 (Console):  http://s30.postimg.org/9utq4ridt/Screen_Shot_2014_09_02_at_9_53_41_PM.png
FireBug 2 (Net Tab):  http://s16.postimg.org/jyblxfcv9/Screen_Shot_2014_09_02_at_9_54_37_PM.png
FireBug 3 (Net Tab - POST):  http://s14.postimg.org/e8czua2wh/Screen_Shot_2014_09_02_at_9_54_47_PM.png

Any idea what I am missing?

(I am using this upload script:  http://www.extremecss.com/creating-asynchronous-file-upload-system-using-html5-file-api/

Comment: Are you returning the CORS headers in the header of your POST response?

Comment: Oh god, I tried that and forgot to restart the server. I changed it and it works.  *duh*  If you add this as an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: Happens to all of us once in a while :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the CORS headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *) within the response header to your POST as well, instead of just within the OPTIONS response.